# How can I give a sizeForItemAt indexPath for all the devices better solution?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

I want to give all my cells sizes to fit on all devices.
Here is the code for my collection view cell sizeForItem at Index Path:

```
extension PersonListViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
  // Cell item size depending on the device height
    let height = self.collectionView.frame.height

        // iPhone SE CollectionView Height
    if height <= 455 {
        return CGSize(width: 155, height: 174)
    }
        // iPhone 8 CollectionView Height
    else if height <= 554 {
        return CGSize(width: 182.5, height: 182.5)
    }
        // iPhone 8 Plus CollectionView Height
    else if height <= 623 {
        return CGSize(width: 202, height: 216)
    }

...
        // iPad Pro 12.9" 3th gen CollectionView Height
    else if height <= 1227 {
        return CGSize(width: 334, height: 340)
    }
    return CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)
 }
}
```

It works correctly and all the devices are bringing to me the good sizes.
But I want to give a better solution to my code. I think I am doing something wrong with the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like below

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
if DeviceType.IS_IPAD{
            return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width-60)/3 , height: (self.view.frame.width-60)/3);
        }
        return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.width-60)/2 , height: (self.view.frame.width-60)/2);

}
```